# Keyword or CLI to create dotnet .vscode folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to create `.vscode` folder by Keyword/CLI, not just waiting system show alert then click yes
[image]
[image]

I've read this doc

- [Command line - vscode](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/command-line/)
- [Keyboard shortcuts - vscode](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization/keyboard-shortcuts/#integrated-terminal)
  but no any helpful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found click `F5` then system will show image select options

[image]

then click `.NET Core` system will auto generate `.vscode` folder

[image]